# MySQL - Updating values in row while keeping primary key

Tags: php, mysql

Scenario:

I have got a client, php script and a MySQL database. I am sending information from the client to the database which the values include the name and favorite color. I have got 2 rows in MySQL database.

Name   |  Favorite Color

Johnny  |     Green

Where Name is a primary key.

Every time, the client would be sending both his name and favorite color. So if name (primary key) exist, it shows error. How should I set my php script to react if the client wants to update his favorite color? In other words, keep primary key but update favorite color.

script.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
mysql_select_db("Information");

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
$color = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["color"]); 

$sql=mysql_query("insert into Male (name, color) VALUES ('$name','$color')"); 

mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Male (name, color) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$color."')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE color='".$color."'");
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) SQL statement. This will update an **existing** row:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE Male SET color = '$color' WHERE name = '$name'");
```

---

Alternatively you can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed.

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Male (name, color) VALUES ('$name','$color') 
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE color = '$color'");
```

---

MySQL offers an SQL extension, namely [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html), which will insert a new row, if none exists.

```
$sql = mysql_query("REPLACE INTO Male (name, color) VALUES ('$name','$color')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to modify your mysql_query with an update statement instead of insert.  Something like this.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);

$color = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["color"]); 

$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE Male SET color = '".$color."' WHERE name = '".$name."'"); 

mysql.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
mysql_select_db("Information");

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
$color = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["color"]); 
$query = mysql_query("select name from Male where name = '$name'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
  mysql_query("update Male set color='$color' where name='$name'");
} else {
   mysql_query("insert into Male (name, color) VALUES ('$name','$color')"); 
}
mysql.close();
?>
```

Comment: What happens when two requests come in close enough to both find 0 rows on the select?  They both try to insert and boom, you have a duplicate key collision bubbling back up to the application.